# Find multiple occurrences of a string between two strings in a column of text in pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, string-search

I have a dataframe with one text column. one of the examples is as follows -

```
line = 'user : hi\nassistant : hi , good evening. how can i help you?\n \n \nuser : order status\nassistant : please enter your case id here. \n \nuser : 0023201. \nassistant : order number: 0023201 \norder amount: 22.5 USD \nplace: oregon \nuser : order status\nassistant : please enter your case id here. \n \nuser : 0023210. \nassistant : order number: 0023210 \norder amount: 18.5 USD \nplace: iowa \n \n'
```

I want to extract the information pf order number, order amount and place into three separate columns. Something like this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['some info','some info','text_column',['0023201','0023210'],['22.5','18.5'],['USD','USD'],['oregon','iowa']]], columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7'])
```

I tried using the 're' module but could not do much.

```
str1 = 'number:'
str2 = 'amount:'
t2 = []
for i in data['text_column']:
    text = i
    reg = "(?<=%s).*?(?=%s)" % (str1,str2)
    r = re.compile(reg,re.DOTALL)
    result = r.findall(r,text)
    t2.append(result)
```

Please help as I am new to python.

Comment: please help in this! i am facing a major roadblock here.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/eztT00/1

Comment: thank you so much! can you please help me build regular expressions if my test string changes a little?

Comment: Yes, sure, just let me know what changes.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?s)user\s*:\s*(\d{7}).*?order amount:\s*(\d[\d.,]*) *([A-Z]+).*?place:\s*([^\r\n]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eztT00/1)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier letting `.` match across lines
- `user` -  a literal string
- `\s*:\s*` - `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{7})` - **Group 1**: seven digits
- `.*?`  - any text up to the first...
- `order amount:` - text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d.,]*)` - **Group 2**: a digit and then 0+ digits, commas or dots
- `*` - 0 or more spaces
- `([A-Z]+)` - **Group 3**: 1+ uppercase letters
- `.*?` - any text up to the first...
- `place:`  - a substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]+)` - **Group 4**: any 1+ chars other than LF/CR